# why do we need a TABLESPACE_VERSION_DIRECTORY in PostgreSQL's tablespace?

Tags: postgresql

I found the files in pg_tblspc under directories like `pg_tblspc/16384/PG_11_201809051/13888/16385`
, and I found they comes from the TABLESPACE_VERSION_DIRECTORY macro.

However, I don't understand why we need this level of directory. Can't we just use `pg_tblspc/16384/13888/16385`? What is the benefit? What will happen if we don't use it? Does it have any relation to the symbol link of tablespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of `TABLESPACE_VERSION_DIRECTORY` is to avoid accidentally using data files with a wrong version of PostgreSQL.  In the main data directory, that purpose is served by the `PG_VERSION` file. One very obvious place where the `TABLESPACE_VERSION_DIRECTORY` shows its power is during an upgrade with `pg_upgrade`: since the tablespace directory location stays the same, the files from the different versions are only distinguished by the different `TABLESPACE_VERSION_DIRECTORY`.